# Get data from ajax array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get ajax array data on PHP side. but I'm having trouble getting the values in PHP. Here's my JavaScript code:

```
console.log(obj);
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/inc/sort_answers.php',
    data: obj,
    success: function(data) {
        if ( data.indexOf('success') != -1) {
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            location.replace('/sort-results/');
        } else {
            alert(data);
        }
    },
```

And output of this js code is:

[image]

I am using this code to get values in PHP:

```
$unsorted = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['unsorted']));
```

But it gives me an error.

Comment: What's the error? It may also help to see the actual content of the `obj` variable, instead of an image of its console representation

Comment: which error does it give to you?

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: stripping slashes out of json is going to corrupt your json...

Comment: and there's no such thing as an "ajax array". ajax is a communications protocol which boils down to being a simple http request. you have a JS array/object.

Comment: Why json_decode? I don’t see you encoding the data as JSON anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by converting your `obj` to JSON, then decode it on the PHP side.

#### Sending an object from Javascript to PHP

Javascript:

```
var enc = JSON.stringify(obj);
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/inc/sort_answers.php',
  data: {obj: enc},
  success: function(data) {
    // Do stuff with data.
});
```

PHP:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['obj'],true);
// Do stuff with $data
```

#### Sending objects from PHP to Javascript:

PHP:

```
$data = array("bla"=>"first entry","arr"=>array("test","more tests"));
echo json_encode($data);
```

Javascript:

```
var obj;
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/inc/sort_answers.php',
  success: function(data) {
    obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Here are a few links about JSON in php and javascript

[JSON decoding for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[JSON encoding for PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[JSON decoding for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

[JSON encoding for JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)